# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name not working on Azure server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

We are moving  a MVC website application to Azure server. On the Azure server we have installed Visual Studio 2015 and currently running the below code successfully.  But same code is not working when hosted on IIS

```
public class HomeController
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
              var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToUpper()
              if(user==NULL)
              {
                Session["userLogin"] = "";
                return View("../Error/NotAuthorized");
              }
              else
              {
                Session["userLogin"] = user.DisplayName;
                Session["User"] = user;
                return View();
              }

        }
}
```

I have omitted some irrelevant code above. I am still not able to understand why the same code which is working when I debug from VS 2015 but, not working when hosted on IIS of the same server. I have only enabled Windows Authentication in IIS. Please help.

Comment: Please, explain the exact issue. When you say not working, are you getting any specific error or it fails at particular line?

Comment: What's the **detail** of your Azure hosting?  You mention that you have `Windows Authentication` enabled - is the Azure server in the relevant AD?

Comment: @RajeshG. Hi. Thanks for your response. When i say not working, the user is being set to NULL, when i have hosted on IIS. But the same code when i run it from VS2015 localhost, HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is returning my username. I access via the IP of the server when i try to access the site from IIS.

Comment: @BrendanGreen. Thanks for your response. The Azure hosting is a Azure external server over internet and not on VNET.

Comment: do you have `Authorize` attribute defined on the controller, method or hosting configuration ?

Comment: Are you using correct authentication mode. Read [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/windows-authentication-forms-based-authentication-when-what/).

Comment: @oleksa. Thanks for your response. I dont have a ```Authorize``` attribute defined.

Comment: @RajeshG. I am using Windows auth as used in the old server which is on-premises.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set load user profile to true in the app pool for the website in IIS.

Also give it correct permissions to access AD if there is one.

[image]